# HTML two forms and two submit on same page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<form id = "msform" action = "" method = "POST">
<input type = "text" name = "name" />
<input type = "submit" name = "submit1" value "Submit" />
</form>
<form id = "msform" action = "" method = "POST">
<b>Name:</b> <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?> 
<input type = "submit" name = "submit2" value "Launch" />
</form>
```

I am using two HTML forms, I want to display one form's data to other any one can guide me that how it is possible??

Comment: first of all you should change your id as it can not be same for both form

Comment: start with unique id's, after that add an onsubmit event on the forms and write it to the other form

Comment: @KevinKloet why should we use js for that simple thing? works fine with php

Comment: @mtizziani it was just a suggestion, php works fine indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, check which button is submitted.

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") 
{
    if ($_POST['submit1'] == 'Submit') {
      // Submit button 
    }
    else 
    {
      // Launch button 
    }
}
```

Comment: I prefer this type of checking on which button is clicked. Safe, simple and clean. Recommended also for starters.

Comment: var form1 = document.getElementById("msform");
form1.onsubmit = function(){
    document.getElementById("msform2").style.display = "block";
};

i was done it like this but 2nd form is not show i think its animation problem of jquery

Answer (score 0):

works fine for me. but a button is a `<button>` and not a input type submit. and never touch global vars like `$_POST` and `$_GET` directly, use `filter_input` for that. the other thing is, an id is only for use 1 time, you used the same id for both forms.

```
<form id="msform1" action="" method="POST">
    <div>
        <input type="text" name="name" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="submit1">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>

<form id="msform2" action="" method="POST">
    <div>
        <b>Name:</b> <?php echo filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'name'); ?> 
    </div>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" name="submit2">
            Launch
        </button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: ok i will try this i think it works fine for my scenario

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using two from in one html page and want to display one form's field value to another on button click. In this case it will be better to use js/jquery. you can easily get one filed value and put into another filed with js/jquery.

```
//Get
var val = $('#field_id').val();

//Set
$('#field_id').val('bla');
```

Comment: But in my case there are many fields if i will do this it will becomes too much lengthy code

Answer (score 0):

```
var form1 = document.getElementById("msform");
 form1.onsubmit = function(){
 document.getElementById("msform2").style.display = "block"; 
};
```

i was done it like this but 2nd form is not show on submit button click i think its animation problem of jquery